# Clientaccesspolicy.xml to be found under a port on Tomcat

Tags: silverlight, tomcat, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I am running a Tomcat 6 server configured to use port 7787.I have to post data from a Silverlight app to a servlet running on this server.Ofcourse this is crossdomain so it requires me to have clientaccesspolicy.xml in the root.

I have seen various questions about this here and on the web and all have the same answer.To put the xml in webapps/ROOT.This works if I try to access the xml via

```
http://somedomain/
```

However since the servlet is running on port 7787 I have to post to somedomain:7787 and thus Silverlight tries to find the xml under

```
http://somedomain:7787/
```

This is unsuccesfull.

I am sure that Silverlight does indeed check somedomain:7787 for the xml as I used Firebug to confirm it.Is there anything in Tomcats configuration I can change or somewhere else I can place the xml so Silverlight can find it under port 7787.Or is there perhaps something I can change on the Silverlight side where the POST is being done?

Comment: For anyone else seeing this and wondering if I found an answer ... no I didn't.

The reason for this is that it is a very stupid question.The reason the post could not find the neccesary xmls is because it was an instance of tomcat launched via eclipse and I had it in the ROOT of my tomcat folder.Thus the xmls weren't in that instance.The right question here is how to put files in the ROOT of a tomcat instance started via eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows machine simply copy the two security files to Tomcat's webapps/ROOT folder
As long as you can get response from ...:7787/crossdomain.xml, anyway solution is OK.
Looks like Silverlight only cares about the response.

I created a Silverlight client and it is OK to get response both from WCF service and Tomcat.